# How to save your game?

Tags: candy-box-2

How do you save? I tried to cut and paste the link but it made me start from the beginning. Sorry, Im not tech savvy :/

Comment: It's possible that something is clearing your cookies.

Answer (score 1):

The save game is stored in your browser. If the link "http://candybox2.net/?slot=1" doesn't restore your game then that means you either didn't save or you cleared your browser. All you have to do to save the game is to spend your candy on the developer features until you unlock the save tab. You then need to click the tab and simply hit "Save on slot 1" or "Save every ten minutes on slot 1". If it still doesn't work, then that means you are most likely clearing your browser and need to either stop clearing it or need to use the text save option directly below the "Save every ten minutes on slot 1" option. It will output a bunch of text that you can copy and save somewhere, then open up candy box and use the text load option by pasting all the text you copied earlier as your save. If that doesn't work, I don't know what else it could be.